# Is there a way to read a CSV file from Google Drive directly into R without downloading the file locally?

Tags: r, read.csv

I have been trying to use the package "googledrive" to read a csv file into R without having it downloaded locally. Is there a way to do this? The only function that seems applicable is drive_download(), which is not doing what I'm looking for. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'without downloading'? Are you expecting the data to be represented in R (e.g., as a data.frame) and hence downloaded, just not perhaps stored temporarily as a file on disk?

Comment: I think you have to download the file and then read it. If the file is too big, you could reduce it's size (remove unwanted columns and rows etc) and write a small version back to googledrive as an RDS or feather format for example.

Comment: @MartinMorgan Yes, that is correct. I want the data frame in R, but not have to save the file locally first (and then download it into R as a separate step). In general, I want to be able to download a data frame directly from cloud storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not tied to using `googledrive`, you can use `googlesheets::gs_read()` to read it straight into R as a data frame.

Comment: So, I had tried using googlesheets, but when I use the command gs_ls() to get started and sign into my google account, I receive an error stating "Sign in with Google temporarily disabled for this app; This app has not been verified yet by Google in order to use Google Sign In."

Comment: This also occurs if I try to register the spreadsheet directly using gs_key().

Comment: Try using `gs_auth(new_user = TRUE)` to authenticate with Google.

Comment: I did try that as well and received the same error.

Comment: use googlesheets4::gs4_deauth() (or googledrive::drive_deauth) to read public files without authentication